# Bash script to sort millions of items by year is too slow

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a folder with about 1.5 MILLION small files.  I also have duplicates in the parents directories already.  So it's a bit of a mess.

They all have a format which includes the date into the filename

I'm trying to sort them by year into parent folder.

This is currently what I have.  But it does only about 3 a second.  Is there something that does below but faster?  I have SAS disks, 32GB ram and Xeon 3.2GHz.  Windows 2012 r2

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in * ; do
    if [[ $f == *_D????98* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../1998/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../1998/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????99* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../1999/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../1999/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????00* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2000/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2000/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????01* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2001/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2001/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????02* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2002/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2002/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????03* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2003/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2003/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????04* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2004/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2004/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????05* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2005/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2005/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????06* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2006/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2006/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????07* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2007/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2007/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????08* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2008/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2008/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????09* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2009/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2009/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????10* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2010/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2010/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????11* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2011/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2011/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????12* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2012/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2012/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????13* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2013/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2013/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????14* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2014/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2014/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????15* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2015/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2015/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????16* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2016/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2016/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????17* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2017/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2017/$f
    fi
    elif [[ $f == *_D????18* ]]
    then
    if ! [[ -e ../../2018/$f ]]
    then
            mv $f ../../2018/$f
    fi
    fi
done
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Comment: Access to a directory with 1.5M file is very slow on windows by definition. What you want to do with the duplicate files ?

Comment: Duplicates I don't care too much.  Delete them I guess.

Comment: @MichaelDeArmon: There is something odd in your problem description: First, if the `*` in your for loop would really expand to that many files, the script would abort with "argument list too long". Second, the body of the loop should execute really quickly. Nothing which would suggest that you can process only 3 files per second - with one exception: If the directories involved are on a network share, Windows can be VERY slow, and this could explain the long running time.

Comment: Showing small output of `tree` and the desired structure may help

Answer (score 0):

There seems some bottleneck factors. The fragment `for f in *` will
create a list of all files at once and will consume some memory.
Some improvements of the posted code may be possible but we cannot expect a drastic change,
as `bash` is not a time-efficient language.
I'd recommend to consider other languages.
If `Perl` is available, please try something like:

```
perl -e '
opendir(D, ".") or die;
while ($f = readdir(D)) {                   # it reads file by file
    next if $f eq "." or $f eq "..";        # skip parent dir and current dir
    if ( -f $f && $f =~ /_D.{4}(\d{2})/) {  # find the matching file
        $yy = $1;                           # extract year
        $year = $yy + 1900;
        if ($yy < 70) {
            $year += 100;
        }
        if (-d "../../$year" && ! -e "../../$year/$f") {
            rename $f, "../../$year/$f";    # move to the desired destination
        }
    }
}'
```

In my benchmark environment, it runs 50 or 100 times faster than the posted script. Hope this helps.